# Which genre is this song reminiscent of?

Tags: rock, electronic-music, identify-this-genre

Here is the link to the song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgZbKq_bxJ4

Now, I know it's an electronic song but I believe Avicii in this album was trying to fuse various genres with electronic music - so my question is, which genre does this song resemble very strongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the start is a sped up sample of the classic [Sweet - The Ballroom Blitz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewFBuYHldeY), released 1974 and it sits comfortably in the glam rock genre, but then the high tight drum sound seems to be more rockabilly, such as the [Stray Cats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk_WpqVFYZg).
It also has a strong beat, with lots of fuzzy and distorted vocals, both from the dance genre.

As I get older I realise more and more that genres mean less and less to me, but whatever it is it definitely a great song.